# Find Consecutive Occurrences within a Group (of IDs)

Tags: r

My data set looks like this:

```
ID start.date  end.date    program
1  2016.05.05  2017.05.05  A
1  2017.05.06  2019.06.16  A
2  2012.06.05  2013.06.18  B
3  2014.09.09  2017.07.01  B
3  2017.09.09  2018.09.09  B
```

I want to identify the people who were present in a program (character variable) consecutively, and then calculate the time between each end.date and start.date (if the occurrence was consecutive).

So the resulting data should look like this:

```
ID start.date  end.date    program  days
1  2016.05.05  2017.05.05  A         NA
1  2017.05.06  2019.06.16  A .       1   
2  2012.06.05  2013.06.18  B .       NA
3  2014.09.09  2017.07.01  B .       NA
3  2017.09.09  2018.09.09  B .       63
```

Don't know how to start on this!

Comment: What defines "consecutively"?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID, program) %>%
  arrange(start.date) %>%  # Added in case the data isn't sorted
  mutate(days = start.date - lag(end.date))
```

I get slightly different results, though:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   ID, program [3]
     ID start.date end.date   program days  
  <int> <date>     <date>     <chr>   <time>
1     1 2016-05-05 2017-05-05 A       NA    
2     1 2017-05-06 2019-06-16 A       1     
3     2 2012-06-05 2013-06-18 B       NA    
4     3 2014-09-09 2017-07-01 B       NA    
5     3 2017-09-09 2018-09-09 B       70
```

To bring the data in, I converted to dates:

```
dat <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, 
text = "ID start.date  end.date    program
        1  2016.05.05  2017.05.05  A
        1  2017.05.06  2019.06.16  A
        2  2012.06.05  2013.06.18  B
        3  2014.09.09  2017.07.01  B
        3  2017.09.09  2018.09.09  B") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("date")), lubridate::ymd)
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess they don't like that you didn't teach the new R user how to convert to dates, nor use a library(...) call.

Comment: I interpreted "consecutive" to mean: "the person does the same program more than once." I did not adjust for the edge case when a person has overlapping enrollments, but it should work the same for longer groups. Perhaps the OP can opine as to how those should be treated, should they potentially exist in the data.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant; I upvoted since I think that interpretation is correct and this is a good way to handle it. But you still need a library(dplyr), right? (Dunno why I wasn't pinged by SO when you replied)

Comment: Thank you! That was super helpful.